# Triggering function only when specific sheet is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I want to add a time stamp every time a cell was updated. I have the basic code down:

```
function onEdit() { 
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
    var c = s.getActiveCell();  
    var cell1 = 13 
    if(c.getColumn() != cell1 ) { 
        var row = c.getRow();  
        var time = new Date(); 
        time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,cell1).setValue(time); 
    };
};
```

But **I want to only trigger it on 1 sheet called** `"VariableMaster"` so I tried:

```
if(c.getColumn() != cell1 && s == "VariableMaster") {....
```

I also tried adding another if statement below that

```
 if(c.getColumn() != cell1 ) { 
      if(s.getActiveSheet == "VariableMaster"){...
```

Both attempts breaks the function and it doesn't add the time stamp to any sheet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter you want to check is the sheet name so you have to compare the sheet **Name**.

Use `if(c.getColumn() != cell1 && s.getName() == "VariableMaster") {....`